# How to divide amcharts colones to 3 parts?

Tags: javascript, plugins, styles

How to divide coloneс to 3 parts divided with lines? They don't have to be in different colors. Here is the plugin - http://www.amcharts.com/ and here is image sample -  http://prikachi.com/images/732/7226732C.png sorry i don't have good enough internet here to upload a demo anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this - http://www.amcharts.com/demos/layered-column-chart/ to view the code of the stats click the blue "Edit" button in top right.